# Upload Videos on facebook as an app

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am developing a website for a one of my customers and this website is accessible in and outside of facebook. For some reasons i need to upload videos on facebook, But the problem is to upload videos not with the user permissions but i want to upload the video by the app.
So my question is to know if is possible to upload videos as the application and not as a user ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not concept of posting "as an application" and not as a user. You can either post the video to a User profile or to a Page. Seems like in you case, you can create a Page for your app and then upload the videos to the Page.